# Is it possible to create a new RSpec matcher by composing existing ones?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In one of my specs, I find myself repeating lines like these often:

```
expect(result.status).to be(:success)
expect(result.offers).not_to be_empty
expect(result.comments).to be_empty
```

To make my tests more succinct and readable, I want to compose these into a line like this:

```
expect(result).to be_successful
```

I can do this by creating a custom matcher:

```
matcher :be_successful do
  match { |result|
    result.status == :success &&
    result.offers.length > 0 &&
    result.comments.empty?
  }
end
```

But I now have a failing test, and the failure message is completely useless. All it says now is `Expected #<Result ...> to be successful`.

I know I can override the failure message, but now this solution is getting more complicated than it's worth for saving 2 lines for every spec example. The original 3 lines generated useful failure messages, all I wanted to do was combine them into 1 line.

I could move the 3 lines into a separate function (e.g. `assert_successful`) and call that from each spec example, but I'd like to keep the matcher syntax.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher)

You could do something like this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_successful do

  match do |result|
    result.status == :success &&
    result.offers.length > 0 &&
    result.comments.empty?
  end

  failure_message do |result|
    "Should have #{result} equal to be successful"
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |result|
    "Should not have #{result} to be successful"
  end
end
```

If you reuse this test elsewhere more than 3 times, then it makes sense to create a new matcher and override the failure messages(It's not an overhead). If you use this test only one time then it makes sense to keep it without overly abstract it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of organizing this is: Put the real testing code into 
a method `_check_ok(expected, actual)` of its own,
which returns either `[true]` or `[false, message]`.

This is called as follows:

```
  RSpec::Matchers.defined :check_ok do |expected|
    match do |actual|
      return _check_ok(expected, actual)[0]
    end
    failure_message do |actual|
      return _check_ok(expected, actual)[1]
    end
  end
```

This repeats the `_check_ok` call in the failure case,
which normally isn't a problem.